# Include with FromSqlRaw and stored procedure in EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, join, entity-framework-core

So here's the deal - I am currently using EF Core 3.1 and let's say I have an entity:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AnotherEntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual AnotherEntity AnotherEntity { get; set; }
}
```

When I access the `DbSet<Entity> Entities` normal way, I include AnotherEntity like:

`_context.Entities.Include(e => e.AnotherEntity)`

and this works. Why wouldn't it, right? Then I go with:

`_context.Entities.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM Entities").Include(e => e.AnotherEntity)`

and this also works. Both return me the same collection of objects joined with AnotherEntity. Then I use a stored procedure which consists of the same query `SELECT * FROM Entities` named spGetEntities:

`_context.Entities.FromSqlRaw("spGetEntities")`

guess what? This also works. It gives me the same output but without joined AnotherEntity, obviously. However if I try to add the Include like this:

`_context.Entities.FromSqlRaw("spGetEntities").Include(e => e.AnotherEntity)`

I am getting:

> FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL
>   and with a query composing over it. Consider calling `AsEnumerable`
>   after the FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the
>   composition on the client side.

Even though the output of `_context.Entities.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM Entities")` and `_context.Entities.FromSqlRaw("spGetEntities")`  is identical.

I couldn't find a proof that I can or I can not do this with EF Core 3.1 but if someone could give me any hint of possibility of this approach it would be nice.

Also if there is another way to get joined entities using stored procedure I would probably accept it as the solution of my issue.

Comment: It's not EF that can't do this. It's SQL itself ("non-composable SQL"), so let alone EF could.

Comment: @GertArnold please add it as an answer. It will help other users too.

Comment: _context.Something.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.spCreateSomething @Id, @Year", sqlParameters).IgnoreQueryFilters().AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

This works for me, you can use ToList() as well over .AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault() to get many.

Comment: Seeing all but the accepted answers below, for whatever reason it seems unclear that this is about using `Include`, *not* about how to use `FromSqlRaw`. The accepted answer is all there is to it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Shortly, you can't do that (at least for SqlServer). The explanation is contained in EF Core documentation - [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) - [Composing with LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#composing-with-linq):

> Composing with LINQ requires your raw SQL query to be composable since EF Core will treat the supplied SQL as a subquery. SQL queries that can be composed on begin with the `SELECT` keyword. Further, SQL passed shouldn't contain any characters or options that aren't valid on a subquery, such as:
>
> - A trailing semicolon
> - On SQL Server, a trailing query-level hint (for example, `OPTION (HASH JOIN)`)
> - On SQL Server, an `ORDER BY` clause that isn't used with `OFFSET 0 OR TOP 100 PERCENT` in the `SELECT` clause
>
> SQL Server doesn't allow composing over stored procedure calls, so any attempt to apply additional query operators to such a call will result in invalid SQL. Use `AsEnumerable` or `AsAsyncEnumerable` method right after `FromSqlRaw` or `FromSqlInterpolated` methods to make sure that EF Core doesn't try to compose over a stored procedure.

Additionally, since `Include` / `ThenInclude` require EF Core `IQueryable<>`, `AsEnumerable` / `AsAsyncEnumerable` etc. is not an option. You really need composable SQL, hence stored procedures are no option.

Instead of stored procedures though, you can use Table-Valued Functions (TVF) or database views because they are composable (`select * from TVF(params)` or `select * from db_view`) .

Comment: This does not work in my case because I am using a derived type. When using derived type from the type that is used in the model, the query is composing even if you call AsEnumerable right after FromSqlRaw. I see no other solution but to make that type not derived, separate with all of the properties from the base type, which is not convenient.

Comment: @HrvojeBatrnek I guess you have in mind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61070935/possible-to-call-a-stored-procedure-on-a-table-per-hierarchy-table-in-ef-core-3/61075446#61075446

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was converting working EF `FromSql()` with a stored procedure 2.1 code to 3.1.
Like so:

```
ctx.Ledger_Accounts.FromSql("AccountSums @from, @until, @administrationId",
                                                            new SqlParameter("from", from),
                                                            new SqlParameter("until", until),
                                                            new SqlParameter("administrationId", administrationId));
```

Where `AccountSums` is a SP.

The only thing I had to do was use `FromSqlRaw()` and add `IgnoreQueryFilters()` to get it working again. Like so:

```
ctx.Ledger_Accounts.FromSqlRaw("AccountSums @from, @until, @administrationId",
               new SqlParameter("from", from),
               new SqlParameter("until", until),
               new SqlParameter("administrationId", administrationId)).IgnoreQueryFilters();
```

This is mentioned in the comments, but I missed that at first so including this here.

Comment: so AccountSums is an SP and @from is another join which include entity sub navigation? seems really odd.. to do this way.. could you give you a usage example.

Comment: And SP parameters

Comment: ok but then does this answer the original question? as my understanding is no... maybe i missed something tho

Comment: If you get a chance please share more of your code. I tried your approach and I still get the darn "non-composable SQL" error. I'm using .Net 6/EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.1 though, it might have broken again.

Comment: There is no more code.. I guess you have a different problem

Comment: Please read the question. How does this solve the `Include` issue?

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to add *.AsEnumerable()* before performing any operation on the result of the raw sql query.

**this fails**

```
var results = ExecuteMyRawSqlQuery(); 
results.Select(r=> r.MyColumn).ToList();
```

**this works**

```
var results = ExecuteMyRawSqlQuery();
results.AsEnumerable().Select(r=> r.MyColumn).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi. You should be aware that as soon as you apply `.AsEnumerable()` to your db set, all the records get evaluated into memory. Thus, any further actions of transforming, filtering and ordering your data are performed on the executing machine.

Comment: Please read the question. How does this solve the `Include` issue?

Answer (score 2):

My solution in the end was to modify my stored procedure to return only Id's. Then I would use EF and find all of my parent object and include the child object. I did need to create a "dummy" entity called "IdTable" but this works and really fast. My stored procedure has some complicated logic in it so I want to keep that fast and then let EF do the rest of the relational data and entity mapping.

This example is from MySQL but MsSQL would work similarly with "Exec" instead of "CALL"

```
 var blogIds = await _persistenceManager.Context.Set<IdTable>().FromSqlRaw($"CALL getBlogIds({query};").ToListAsync();

 return _persistenceManager.GetEntities<Blog>().AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(i => i.Tags)
                    .Where(pa => blogIds.Select(i => i.Id).Contains(pa.Id));
```

Here is the "dummy" model

```
public partial class IdTable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And for the DBContext

```
public virtual DbSet<IdTable> IdTables { get; set; }
```