# use stored procedure with EFCore5.0 error System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using the latest EF.core version (5.0.7) and attempting to retrieve entities via stored procedure.
Tried the following:

```
 //attemp 1
 res = _context.Entity.FromSqlRaw($"exec dbo.ProcedureName");
 //attemp 2
 res = _context.Entity.FromSqlRaw("exec ProcedureName", new SqlParameter("@ParamName", paramValue));
 //attemp 3
 res = _context.Entity.FromSqlRaw($"exec ProcedureName {paramValue}");
 //attemp 4
 res = _context.Entity.FromSqlInterpolated($"exec ProcedureName @ParamName = {paramValue}");
 //attemp 5
 res = _context.Entity.FromSqlInterpolated($"exec ProcedureName {paramValue}");
```

All of the examples and without the "exec", parameter name with and without "@" and procedure name with and without leading "dbo"
I keep getting the error "System.InvalidOperationException: FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-compostable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling AsEnumerable after the FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the composition on the client-side."
what am I doing wrong?

P.S.

Client-side composition is not an option.

The procedure works fine in SSMS.

In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61070935/possible-to-call-a-stored-procedure-on-a-table-per-hierarchy-table-in-ef-core-3) This was claimed to be an issue resolved by EF5.0, but it clearly isn't.

Comment: wrap the stored procedure call with `select * from (exec ...)`

Comment: Fixed is different issue. Composing over SPs in SqlServer can't be done (try doing it in SQL and you'll see). Replacing SPs with TVFs in the only option.

Comment: select * from (exec ...) is incorrect syntax in SSMS and throws "SqlException" of "Incorrect syntax" in C#

Comment: example of composing over SP `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (exec ProcedureName)`. This is not a valid SQL query. So you need to call `FromSqlRaw(...).AsEnumerable()`

Comment: Thanks @FireAlkazar, but this is not what I'm doing is it? or maybe because I'm using the ` _context.Entity` to run this SP it automatically surrounds it with a "SELECT" ?

Comment: have you tried EXECUTE instead of EXEC?

Comment: @Elizur we are guessing here. Could you try your attempts as follows `res = _context.Entity.FromSqlRaw($"exec dbo.ProcedureName").AsEnumerable()`?
It works fine for me to call SP this way in EF 5.0.7

Comment: @FireAlkazar thanks , but I've tried this in every one of my attempts, all this does is allowing client side composition witch is not relevant for SP.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `FromSqlRaw`, you need to let *it* do the interpolation, it will convert it to parameters. **Do not** do it yourself.

```cs
res = _context.Entity
  .FromSqlRaw("exec ProcedureName @ParamName = {paramValue}", paramvalue)
  .AsEnumerable();
```

Note the lack of the `$`. You also need to add `AsEnumerable` [to prevent it from trying to compose it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59382180/14868997).

Comment: FromSqlInterpolated only accepts one parameter of type "FormatedString" so your code doesn't compile

Comment: @Elizur You're right, I meant `FromSqlRaw`. And you need to add `AsEnumerable`

Comment: no such luck. I still get the exact same error as before. besides - AsEnumerable() is trying to convert it to client side composition (filtering via Linq) and that is out of the question. But what do you mean with = {paramValue}" I'm guessing that you mean = {0}" (like in the old String.Format())

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework [throws the exception](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v5.0.11/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/QuerySqlGenerator.cs#L483) preventing server-side composition unless the query starts with "SELECT".

```
if (char.ToLowerInvariant(c) == 's'
    && char.ToLowerInvariant(NextChar()) == 'e'
    && char.ToLowerInvariant(NextChar()) == 'l'
    && char.ToLowerInvariant(NextChar()) == 'e'
    && char.ToLowerInvariant(NextChar()) == 'c'
    && char.ToLowerInvariant(NextChar()) == 't')
{
    var (c1, c2) = (NextChar(), NextChar());
    if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c1)
        || c1 == '-' && c2 == '-'
        || c1 == '/' && c2 == '*')
    {
        return;
    }
}

throw new InvalidOperationException(RelationalStrings.FromSqlNonComposable);
```

You specifically mention *"Client-side composition is not an option"* but as [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68206153/use-stored-procedure-with-efcore5-0-error-system-invalidoperationexception#comment120548989_68206153), SQL Server does not support composition over stored procedures. The recommendation to re-write as a table-valued function may be possible if it can be done without side effects that modify the database state.

There's a [whole pile of issues](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21888) related to FromSql and mapping, some of which reference composition. I believe [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24157) indicates that EF5.0 only resolved the 'non-composable' exception for root table-per-hierarchy entities.