# Performing UPDATE - OUTPUT query in EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

In EF Core 2, I was able to update and retrieve entities in a single query using `FromSql` and issuing an `UPDATE-OUTPUT` query.

It looked something like this:

```
return await _baseDbContext.MyEntity
                           .FromSql($@"UPDATE {_baseDbContext.SchemaName}.MyEntity
                            SET STATUS = ""InProgress"",
                                UpdatedAt = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
                            OUTPUT
                                INSERTED.Id, INSERTED.Name,
                                INSERTED.Status, INSERTED.Deleted, INSERTED.CreatedAt, INSERTED.CreatedBy, INSERTED.CreatedByUserId,
                                INSERTED.UpdatedAt, INSERTED.UpdatedBy, INSERTED.UpdatedByUserId, INSERTED.Version
                            FROM { _baseDbContext.SchemaName}.MyEntity le
                            WHERE le.Status = ""Failed""")
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Now after upgrading to EF Core 3, it is complaining that

> "FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling `AsEnumerable` after the FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the composition on the client side.

I am able to perform a `FromSqlRaw` or `FromSqlInterpolated` if I just put in a `SELECT` query.

Does EF core 3 not support `UPDATE-OUTPUT` queries anymore?

Comment: what would of been easier to to code the actual code instead of the output, well both would of helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding `.IgnoreQueryFilters()` based on the the answer posted here: 
[Include with FromSqlRaw and stored procedure in EF Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59908321/7393354)