# Asp .net core web api Entity Framework 5.0 Lazy loading

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, lazy-loading

i have the following client model that has a relation with orders and BloodType tables:

```
 public partial class Client
    {
        public Client()
        {
            ClientOrders = new HashSet<ClientOrder>();
        }

        public long ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public long BloodTypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual BloodType BloodType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ClientOrder> ClientOrders { get; set; }
    }
```

when i try the following code to lazy load the orders and the BloodType it's not rendering them and it return the as empty list and null value.

here's my code:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("clients-orders")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetClientsOrders()
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _trainingContext.Clients.FromSqlRaw("Exec getClients").ToListAsync();
                var clientsOrders = new List<Client>();
                foreach (var client in result)
                {
                    Client currentClient = new Client()
                    {
                        ClientId = client.ClientId,
                        BloodTypeId = client.BloodTypeId,
                        PhoneNumber = client.PhoneNumber,
                        ClientOrders = client.ClientOrders,
                        BloodType = client.BloodType
                    };
                    clientsOrders.Add(currentClient);
                }

                return Ok(clientsOrders);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Any solution would be very appreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean EF Core 5 or EF 5 - they are 2 different beasts. I assume you mean EF Core 5 given you've also tagged ASP.NET Core

Comment: yess sorry, i mean EF core 5

Comment: You need to use the .include method, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381530/include-with-fromsqlraw-and-stored-procedure-in-ef-core-3-1