# Use stored procedure with linq method (without loading into memory)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Is it possible to use a stored procedure along with a Linq EF query without calling AsEnumerable (Not loading the entire result into memory)

```
var transactions =  (_plineContext.TrkallTransactions
            .FromSqlRaw("exec apiTransactionGet @LoginId", loginId).Take(10).ToList());
```

but I get error:

> 'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59382180/1464084

Comment: Only if it is Table-Valued function. It is SQL Server limitation.